# How to get previously install package information?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, grep, logs

Is there a way using dpkg, apt, logs, or any thing else, where I can query/retrieve previously **installed** versions of an application? I don't care about which previous versions were available up to the current version installed, I need to know the **previous version installed**.

**This is my real world example:**

I have 200+ Ubuntu/Debian servers. I installed [the first update to bash](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2362-1/) which patched the shellshock bug. But now [there is a second](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2363-2/)...

I'm tasked to document what version we upgraded from originally on each of these machines, because we now have to document what version we are updating to as that task of reaching all 200 machines was not completed and change management is now all screwed up and needs to start from scratch with all versions (previously installed, currently installed, version to be upgraded to). I hope that makes sense, a lot of test for a simple question, I just wanted to make it clear why I'd need this.

Thanks for your consideration and ideas. I'm leaning towards grepping logs, but I am looking for any better solutions.